# Weird MySQL query plan: why is this query using temporary & filesort? How to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM amp_ads,amp_c,amp_c_countries    
WHERE 
(amp_c.zone = '24' OR amp_c.zone = '25') AND 
amp_ads.ad_complete = '1' AND 
amp_ads.ad_type = '17' AND 
amp_ads.accept = '1' AND 
amp_ads.en_w = '1' AND 
amp_c.en_u = '1' AND 
amp_c.en_w = '1' AND 
(amp_c.i_nu>'0' OR amp_c.c_nu>'0' OR amp_c.d_valid_by>'1299341823' OR amp_c.unlimit='1') AND 
(amp_c.i_d_max='0' OR amp_c.i_d_nu>'0') AND 
(amp_c.c_d_max='0' OR  amp_c.c_d_nu>'0') AND 
amp_c.t1<'1299341823' AND 
amp_c.t2>'1299341823' AND 
amp_c.d7 = '1'  AND 
(amp_c.some_countr = '0' OR (amp_c_countries.country = 'ES' AND amp_c.n = amp_c_countries.ad AND amp_c.camp = amp_c_countries.c))  AND 
amp_c.n = amp_ads.n AND 
amp_ads.def = 0       
ORDER BY amp_c.price_c desc LIMIT 1
```

(It's actually not `SELECT *`, but I simplified the `SELECT` clause to make it less messy.)

The output of `EXPLAIN` of the above query is:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: amp_c
         type: ref
possible_keys: work,n_index,zone_price
          key: zone_price
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 79
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: amp_ads
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: n,work
          key: n
      key_len: 4
          ref: advertis_admpro.amp_c.n
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: amp_c_countries
         type: index
possible_keys: work
          key: work
      key_len: 12
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4083
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using join buffer
```

1) Why is the 1st table `Using temporary` and `Using filesort`? `EXPLAIN` show that it is using the index `zone_price`, which is made up of 2 columns: `(zone, price_c)`. So after the index is used to select rows based on the `zone` value, all the resulting rows are in the order of price_c. And since the query is ORDER BY price_c, there should be no need for `Using temporary` and `Using filesort` at all. What am I missing?

2) For the 3rd table, it is supposed to be using the index `work`. But yet ref is `NULL`. What does that mean? `work` is made up of the columns `(ad,c,country)`. So when rows are selected from `amp_c_countries` using the `WHERE` clause `(amp_c_countries.country = 'ES' AND amp_c.n = amp_c_countries.ad AND amp_c.camp = amp_c_countries.c)`, shouldn't it be just a simple index lookup? The `rows` value in `EXPLAIN` is 4083, `amp_c_countries` has 4113 rows according to `SHOW TABLE STATUS`. Does that mean MySQL is doing a full index scan instead of a lookup?

3) Any ideas on how to fix the above 2 problems? `amp_ads` contains `TEXT` columns, so a lot of disk temp tables are being created:

```
| Created_tmp_disk_tables               | 906952      |
| Created_tmp_files                     | 11          |
| Created_tmp_tables                    | 912227      |
```

`show processlist` also shows many processes are in the state of `Copying to tmp table`.

Thanks. Appreciate your help.

**EDIT**:

Outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `advertis_admpro`.`amp_c`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: amp_c
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `amp_c` (
  `n` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `camp` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zone` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `javascript` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banner_target` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `accept` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_u` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_w` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `i_got` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_got` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `r` double(4,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price_i` double(10,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price_c` double(10,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `i_nu` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_nu` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unlimit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_total` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_valid_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `t1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `t2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d7` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tz5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `some_countr` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `i_d_max` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_d_max` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `i_d_nu` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c_d_nu` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emailed` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `work` (`en_u`,`en_w`,`i_nu`,`c_nu`,`d_valid_by`,`unlimit`,`i_d_max`,`c_d_max`,`i_d_nu`,`c_d_nu`,`t1`,`t2`,`n`),
  KEY `n_index` (`n`,`camp`),
  KEY `zone_price` (`zone`,`price_c`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `advertis_admpro`.`amp_ads`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: amp_ads
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `amp_ads` (
  `n` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ad_type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accept` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_w` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weight` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `w` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `h` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `norepeat` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `campaigns` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zones` text NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `banner` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `alt` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `raw` text NOT NULL,
  `kind` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `javascript` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ad_complete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url1` text NOT NULL,
  `url2` text NOT NULL,
  `url3` text NOT NULL,
  `text1` text NOT NULL,
  `text2` text NOT NULL,
  `text3` text NOT NULL,
  `text4` text NOT NULL,
  `text5` text NOT NULL,
  `text6` text NOT NULL,
  `text7` text NOT NULL,
  `text8` text NOT NULL,
  `text9` text NOT NULL,
  `text10` text NOT NULL,
  `picture1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture3` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture4` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `preview` text NOT NULL,
  `def` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `n` (`n`),
  KEY `work` (`ad_type`,`accept`,`en_w`,`norepeat`,`ad_complete`,`def`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1532 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE `advertis_admpro`.`amp_c_countries`\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: amp_c_countries
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `amp_c_countries` (
  `ad` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `c` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `country` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY `work` (`ad`,`c`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It is impossible to help without providing the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for each of your tables. Also, using `WHERE` to join tables instead of `JOIN` often leads to confusing the MySQL query planner.

Comment: I have included the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: @hobodave have you got a link to the MySQL docs talking about your comment *Also, using `WHERE` to join tables instead of `JOIN` often leads to confusing the MySQL query planner*? I've used WHERE to join tables for years without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes tend not to be used when the values are used in a `OR` condition. `(amp_c.zone = '24' OR amp_c.zone = '25')` may be better written as `(`amp_c.zone BETWEEN '24' AND '25')`.

Indexes tend not to be used when they occur on one side of an OR but not the other.  Use of `amp_c.some_countr = '0' OR (...)` will likely invalidate use of the index.m

Optimizers work better with simple equalities.  You may need outer joins rather than inner joins.